# distinct classes using `with` in Python

Tags: python, class, metaclass, with-statement

If you have the following class:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(name):
        self.name = name
```

And you use it like this in a file called check_foo.py

```
with Foo("naming it"):
    print Foo.name


with Foo("naming another"):
    print Foo.name
```

If you import `check_foo` and run `dir(check_foo)` you will only get a single `check_foo.Foo` module.

I know that PEP 343 mentions that you can do something like:

```
with Foo("naming it") as naming_it:
    print naming_it.name
```

And that it would get instantiated properly in `check_foo` as `check_foo.naming_it` but my question is it is possible to work around this and set the name dynamically.

I'm playing around with a proof of concept and want to know how far I can get with the above idea.

Could it be possible to name the instance using the string I am passing to `Foo` ?

Note: I am also aware about `withhacks`. Let's not suggest I take a look at that :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "naming" an instance? I assume you want to create a variable that refers to the instance, but where (what scope)?

Comment: you are correct, I need to define those classes as something different than 'Foo' so that when I get to import `check_foo` I can get *my* definitions and not a single `check_foo.Foo`instance.

Comment: makes no sense to me, what does " to name the instance using the string I am passing" mean? And how does the `with` statement come into play? It's not some kind of `let`, right?

Comment: -1: horrid abuse of Python namespaces.

Comment: It is correct to explain "bad practices" or "bad ideas/implementations" in a specific language when someone proposes such a thing in a question. It is absolutely **not** correct to simply say "this is horrid" and down-vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the sort of hackery that you are looking for...

```
import inspect

class renameable(object):
  def rename_me(self, new_name):
    for stack_frame in inspect.stack()[1:]:
      frame_object = stack_frame[0] # frame is the first object in the tuple
      for (name, value) in frame_object.f_locals.iteritems():
        if value is self:
          old_name = name
          matched_frame = frame_object
          break
      if matched_frame:
        break
    if matched_frame:
      matched_frame.f_locals[new_name] = matched_frame.f_locals[old_name]
      del matched_frame.f_locals[old_name]
```

I doubt that this is a complete solution, but it does allow you to change one binding of a value to a name.  It changes the name that is bound to the value which is closest to the call of `rename_me`.  For example:

```
>>> import blah
>>> x = blah.renameable()
>>> x
<blah.renameable object at 0x1004cb790>
>>> x.rename_me('y')
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>> y
<blah.renameable object at 0x1004cb790>
>>>
```

I'm not sure if this is better or worse than using `withhacks` but it does delve into a seldom explored module in the library.